# Prevent Start Menu, Camera button from tombstoning WP7 Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, tombstoning

I have a WP7 application that I've disabled the idle capabilities of the phone with such as:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = 
                                                        IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

However, the camera button and start menu still pause the application and resume it afterwards. I want the app to run regardless of these buttons being pushed. How can I prevent these buttons from tombstoning the app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tombstoning always occurs if the user presses the `windows key` or `camera button`. The code you've shown ensures that your app will continue to run under a lock screen, not if it will run when your app is tombstoned. In the current version (7.0), there is no multitasking for third parties, whereas Mango (7.1) allows for some more freedom with respect to multitasking.

Presumably this app is targetted at 7.0, so your app will be tombstoned and you will have to handle it. There is no way of having your app continue running in the background.

On a side note, you'll still have to handle tombstoning in Mango as well, but you do get more abilities to run your app in the background.

Comment: Is there anyway I can temporarily disable the camera button if the user grants that?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The only hardware button you can currently override is the `back button`. The Windows key, camera button and search button can't be accessed by third parties in the current version.